# sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace  `filter = [ "a/.*/" ]` with

`filter = [ "a\/sda1\/", "a\/sdb\/", "r/\.\*\/"]`

I have tried this regex

`sed -i -r 's/\s+filter\s=.*/'filter = [ "a\/sda1\/","a\/sdb\/", "r/\.\*\/"]'/' conf` 
But getting this error. Please advice.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: remove the single quotes around the filter part.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte got this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: If you give example text (before/after), we may be able to create a solution for you that even may be better.

Comment: @Jotne It's in my question itself . That is the replacement exactly I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the `/` delimiter more in the field ,instead of `/` use some other delimiter like `s#pattern#replace#` .
Another thing is you have to replace each and every special meaning character to literal values .
So The below command are helpful to get expect  result.

```
sed  -r -i -e 's#(filter = )(\[ "a/\.\*/" \])#\1[ "a\/sda1\/", "a\/sdb\/", "r/\.\*\/"]#g' conf
```

Comment: @Harikrishnan,You are most welcome.